# Static class member

Tags: c++

What's wrong with the code below? Latest version of g++ and clang both give error. I am sure I am missing something basic here.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Z
{
  static const int mysize = 10; 
};

Z f2();

int main()
{
    std::cout << f2()::mysize << std::endl;
}
```

The motivation here is to be able to find out the size of an array using templates using code such as below. I know there are many ways, but just stumbled upon this idea.

```
template<int N> struct S
{
    enum { mysize = N };
};

template<class T, int N> S<N> f(T (&)[N]);

int main()
{
    char buf[10];
    std::cout << f(buf)::mysize << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f2()` returns a value, not a type. You'd need to use the `.` operator on the return value instead of `::`

The `::` operator requires a type to be named on the lefthand side, while `.` allows for a value to be named. Your expression `f2()` does not name a type so it cannot be used in conjunction with `::`.

As a side note, with a little more detail in the question we might be able to solve your real problem.

Comment: but isn't my expression same as Z::mysize?

Comment: @Chubsdad `::` should have a class (struct) or namespace on its left, but in your example it has an object of type `Z` returned by `f2`. Use `.` to reference the `mysize` member of the object.

Comment: the type of expression 'f2()' is 'Z'. Hence I think i can use the type on the lhs of ::

Comment: Ok, got it. In C++11, we can use 'decltype' and solve this issue

Comment: @Chubsdad Well, you may think that, but it is wrong. The left side of `::` requires a type or a namespace. Even though the object returned *has* a type, it is not a type.

Comment: @us2012: yes, I realize that now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your program contains two mistakes:

1. You are using the `::` operator to access the member of an *object*. Use `operator .` ("dot") instead;
2. You declare function `f2()` and invoke it without defining it (this will give you a linker error).

Also, since `static` member variables are shared among all instances of a class (`Z` in this case), you do not need an object to access it;

Here is how you could fix your program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Z
{
    static const int mysize = 10;
};

Z f2() { return Z(); }

int main()
{
    // Don't need an object to access a static variable...
    std::cout << Z::mysize << std::endl;

    // ...but if you really want to, do it this way...
    std::cout << f2().mysize << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this way to find out the size of array by templates:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<int N> struct S
{
    enum { mysize = N };
};

template<class T, int N> int f1(T (&)[N])
{
        return N;
}

int main()
{
    char buf[10];
    std::cout << f1(buf) << std::endl;

}
```

And this one is closer to your variant:

```cpp
template<class T, int N> S<N> f(T (&)[N])
{
        S<N> foo;
        return foo;
}


int main()
{
    char buf[10];
    std::cout << f(buf).mysize << std::endl;
}
```

Anyway, you will need to return an object from `f` and access it's member by `.`, not by `::`.
But it's more probable that second variant will be slower, because first variant is fully compile-time, but in the second variant compiler may miss the optimization and don't optimize out the run-time creation of `foo`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add `const int Z::mysize;` after class declaration.

Comment: I think that with modern versions of C++/modern C++ compilers you can define const, static variables inside the class definition.